# Jquery removing and changing html tags

Tags: jquery

I have couple of hyperlinks on my website. What I want is to remove the a href html tag if they match with a given condition.

Example

if href is example.com then, hyperlink should be dissolved and `<a></a>` tag should disappear

I have been using the following statement,

```
$("a[href='http://www.example.com']").removeAttr("href");
```

the href is going to be removed but `<a>` is still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nicest way to do this is with [`contents`](http://api.jquery.com/contents) and [`unwrap`](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap):

```
$("a[href='http://www.example.com']").contents().unwrap();
```

This says:

- find all the links that match the selector
- get all their child nodes
- unwrap the child nodes from their parent, i.e. replace the `a` element with its child nodes

Answer (score 3):

You could use [.remove](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) to remove the whole element.

```
$("a[href='http://www.example.com']").remove();
```

Answer (score 2):

To preserve the link's text, but remove the link itself:

```
$("a[href='http://www.example.com']").replaceWith(function() {
    return $(this).text();
});
```

use `.html()` instead if there are other HTML tags within the link that you wish to preserve.

Comment: It would be better to do `return this.childNodes;` This would be quicker and would avoid losing data/event handlers.

Comment: @lonesomeday nice one - that's definitely better than `.html()`, and simpler than cloning them too!

Answer (score 1):

To remove the anchor element try this:

```
$("a[href='http://www.example.com']").remove();
```

For more info see the[`.remove()` doco](http://api.jquery.com/remove/).

EDIT: To replace the anchor element with its content try this:

```
$("a[href='http://www.example.com']").replaceWith(function() {
    return $(this).html();
});
```

The [`.replaceWith()` method](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) does what you might expect. If you pass it a function then that function will be called for each matching element, with `this` being the current element that will be replaced by the return from the function.

Comment: Or my updated answer. (Sorry, initially I misunderstood what you were asking. Actually I think your question is still a bit unclear - you might want to edit it to make it more obvious that you want to keep each anchor's contents.) But I recommend lonesomeday's answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("a[href='http://www.example.com']").remove(); 
$("a[href='http://www.example.com']").unwrap(); -> also check this :D
```

Answer (score 0):

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/3utk7/

**code**

```
$('a').each(function() {
    var foo = $(this).attr("href");
    if (foo == "http://www.example.com") {
        $(this).remove();

    }
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the whole tag with :

```
$("a[href='http://www.example.com']").find().remove();
```